# JavaScript Ajax SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' in IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

```
 var url="tabla.php";
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:url,
    data:{place,names,repor},
    success: function(datos){       
      $('#tabla').html(datos);
    }
```

This code works in Chrome but in IE 11 returns the error `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'` on line 5. I'd really appreciate any help.

**Note:** `place` and `names` are arrays that are previously defined, and `repor` is also a previously defined variable.

Comment: data:{place,names,repor} is not valid js object.  Is that supposed to be an array?  ie.  data:[place,names,repor] ?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if that worked in chrome. It's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: You still need to define the name of the property that will hold that value inside of the object you are passing. `data:{place: place, names: names, repor: repor} `

Comment: @Rooster and ShamSUP, you guys might want to test the code before you tell him what's wrong. Pop `({window, document})` in your console and tell me if you get an error. :P ES2015 FTW!

Comment: @JeremyBanks that works in an IE11 console?  :P  actually what console are you using that that works in?

Comment: @Rooster It works in Chrome but you might need 'Enable Experimental Javascript' enabled in chrome://flags, its an ES6 feature

Comment: @ryan ahhh, right that makes sense.  Unfortunately, microsoft made using cool stuff like that universally hard for a while :/  Jerks

Comment: Thanks ShamSUP, your recomendation works perfectly in IE 11 (as well in Chrome)

Answer (score 25):

Usually objects in JavaScript are initialized as key value pairs, so data should probably be initialized like

```
data:{ place : place, names : names, report : report }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

In ECMAScript 2015 it seems you can omit the key part in certain situations, which is why it works on Chrome.

Comment: its hard to say this is valid or invalid based on the information the OP provided.  Good guess though.

Answer (score 22):

I had the SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' error as well in IE 11 (and my code worked fine in Chrome & Firefox). If someone uses Knockoutjs and encounters this, watch out for the syntax when stating functions in your view model:

```
var viewModel = {
    property1: "",
    functionWorksInAllBrowsers: function (arg1, arg2) {
        // ...
    },
    functionThrowsErrorInInternetExplorer11(arg1, arg2) { 
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: not only knockout but IE 11 does not support shorthand for functions. So, you need to use as suggested in this answer or use a babel polyfill.