# Vue.js Syntax Error (SCRIPT1003) IE11 and lower

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, vue.js, vuex

When i try my vue.js app in IE11 or lower i get Error SCRIPT1003 excepted : in the console which points to routeContent. My Snytax looks like this:

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        routeContent: null
    },
    mutations: {
        routeContent(state, payload) {
            state.routeContent = payload
            document.title = payload.title
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using a transpiler (e.g. Babel)?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the [object method shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions) in your definition of `routeContent` - [this isn't supported in Internet Explorer or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility).

The two options you have are to either start using a transpiler such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to convert modern JS syntax into a form that older browsers can understand - or, if that's too much hassle, you could just switch back to using the good old-fashioned function syntax:

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        routeContent: null
    },
    mutations: {
        routeContent: function (state, payload) {
            state.routeContent = payload
            document.title = payload.title
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Not what I wanted to read after developing a website using Vue.js without transpiling!  But helpful - one shouldn't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another similar question: [javascript Ajax SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808557/javascript-ajax-script1003-expected-in-ie-11)

I think you may have to do as follows:

```js
mutations: {
    routeContent: function(state, payload) {  // making it obvious that this is a function
        state.routeContent = payload;
        document.title = payload.title;  // and also the semicolons
    }
}
```

Comment: Or another option is to use Babel with webpack/browserify, so he could write his code in ES2015, and without semicolons :)

Comment: Yes, Babel with webpack is definitely a better solution, because the next problem in IE 11 is [arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) :-)

Comment: Solved my problem. thanks folks, we are using vue actually client-side, any sugestions to achieve transpiling in atom editor?

Comment: You can use an atom editor package like [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel). It has the option to **transpile-on-save**. But I believe you should be able to achieve the same by using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), which can do far more like server proxying for dev, minifying and making a production build, etc., while also taking care of transpiling during development.